# C# TripleDES encryption bad data

Tags: c#, encryption

I want to encrypt a file, save it to an xml. After that i want to read the xml get out the data and decrypt it and save to file. I've got encryption and decryption method but when I try to decrypt it I got an exception "Bad data".
Encryptin code:

```
public string EncryptData(byte[] fileData, byte[] tdesKey, byte[] tdesIV)
        {
            MemoryStream msInput = new MemoryStream(fileData);
            MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
            msOutput.SetLength(0);            

            //Create variables to help with read and write.
            byte[] bin = new byte[100]; //This is intermediate storage for the encryption.
            long rdlen = 0;              //This is the total number of bytes written.
            long totlen = msInput.Length;    //This is the total length of the input file.
            int len;                     //This is the number of bytes to be written at a time.

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            switch (mw.cmb_encryption_mode.Text)
            {
                case "ECB": tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; break;
                case "CBC": tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; break;
                case "CFB": tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB; break;
                case "OFB": tdes.Mode = CipherMode.OFB; break;
                default: break;
            }
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            tdes.Key = tdesKey;
            tdes.IV = tdesIV;
            CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(msOutput, tdes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            mw.encryption_progress_bar.Maximum = totlen;

            //Read from the input file, then encrypt and write to the output file.
            while (rdlen < totlen)
            {
                len = msInput.Read(bin, 0, 100);
                encStream.Write(bin, 0, len);
                rdlen = rdlen + len;

                mw.encryption_progress_bar.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => mw.encryption_progress_bar.Value = rdlen, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
            }

            encStream.Close();
            byte[] resultArray = msOutput.GetBuffer();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
        }
```

Decryption code:

```
public byte[] DecryptData(byte[]encryptedData, byte[] tdesKey, Header header, byte[] tdesIV)
        {
            MemoryStream msInput = new MemoryStream(encryptedData);
            MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
            msOutput.SetLength(0);

            //Create variables to help with read and write.
            byte[] bin = new byte[100]; //This is intermediate storage for the encryption.
            long rdlen = 0;              //This is the total number of bytes written.
            long totlen = msInput.Length;    //This is the total length of the input file.
            int len;                     //This is the number of bytes to be written at a time.

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            switch (header.cipherMode)
            {
                case "ECB": tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; break;
                case "CBC": tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; break;
                case "CFB": tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB; break;
                case "OFB": tdes.Mode = CipherMode.OFB; break;
                default: break;
            }
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            tdes.Key = tdesKey;
            tdes.IV = tdesIV;
            CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(msOutput, tdes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            mw.decryption_progress_bar.Maximum = totlen;

            //Read from the input file, then encrypt and write to the output file.
            while (rdlen < totlen)
            {
                len = msInput.Read(bin, 0, 100);
                encStream.Write(bin, 0, len);
                rdlen = rdlen + len;
                mw.decryption_progress_bar.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => mw.decryption_progress_bar.Value = rdlen, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
            }            
            encStream.Close(); // <-exception

            return msOutput.GetBuffer();
        }
```

If I encrypt and decrypt the same data using ICryptoTransform and TransformFinalBlock function, everything works well, but i need to update progress on progress bar every processed block. I cant figure it out why it doesnt work, is there something im doing wrong?

Comment: Why use 3DES, AES is the current encryption standard and has a stronger key size. 3DES (with three keys) has an effective key length of 112-bits due to a meet-in-the-middle attack, AES supports key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bits.

Comment: It's academic project, i have to use 3des.

Comment: `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` is not the method you want. You want `MemoryStream.ToArray()`. You could also save yourself the pain of writing a read loop by just using the `CopyTo()` method. e.g. `msInput.CopyTo(encStream)`

Comment: Could you print out the key and IV as hexadecimals after encryption and before decryption? Why is your encryption routine using base 64 and is this missing from the decryption routine? Your methods should be *symmetric* (if one encodes, then the other one should decode). Mixing UI and encryption / decryption is not a good idea. If you want to report create an `IReportListener` and create an implementation of it to perform the actual UI code.

Comment: Thanks a lot James, that was the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why I got error "Bad data" was using `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` instead of `MemoryStream.ToArray()` just as James wrote in comment:

> MemoryStream.GetBuffer() is not the method you want. You want MemoryStream.ToArray().